# to proxy http requests made from a nodejs app to fiddler

Tags: node.js, proxy, fiddler

as the article says:
https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler-everywhere/knowledge-base/how-to-capture-nodejs-traffic

is it possible to proxy globaly the traffic to fiddler except for the libraries that use the http module, other libraries that use `http module`, on the other hand, needs to be proxied explicitly

I need to inspect the traffic generated from a node app, which i don't know what type of library it uses.
i've tryed to proxy globally but i doesn't works

```
process.env.https_proxy='http://127.0.0.1:8888';
process.env.http_proxy='http://127.0.0.1:8888';
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0;
```

does it exist a workaround?